# How to fetch result after updating in mongodb?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I am working on node js application using mongo db.I stuck in res.json portion.It display result of keyword before the updated one.I want if user enter the keyword then as a result it should display in json but before new keyword is displayed in res.json while in mongodb keyword successfully update.Where am i Doing wrong??

```
app.post('/keyword', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
               User.update({_id:req.user._id},{$addToSet:{keyword:req.body.tags}},function (err, result) {
                    if (err) return handleError(err);

                    return true;
                  });
                  console.log(w);
                  res.json({user:req.user})

        })
```

Suppose i have 'lio' already in keyword array then and when i type 'apple ' then it should display both result but it display only lio keyword.And after page reload it displays both keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way. JavaScript is an **asynchronous** language. In your case, the function is returning data without waiting for the response. Basically, the data is returned before the update functionality is executed. To solve this, return the user data inside the update function only.

```
app.post('/keyword', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {  
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user._id},{$addToSet:
       {keyword:req.body.tags}, {returnNewDocument: true}},(err, result) => {
       if (err) return handleError(err);

       return res.json({user:user, result:result, flag: 1});
    });
});
```

You can send a flag variable to check if the value has been properly updated or not.

Comment: instead of {returnNewDocument: true} it works on { new: true }.Btw thanks for reference.

Comment: {returnNewDocument: true} has been added in mongo db 3.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would attempt to push the array of tags into a single matching document, using the `user._id` value as the condition.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(

    // <filter>
    {_id:req.user._id},

    // <update>
    {$push:{keyword: {$each: req.body.tags}}},

    // <options>
    {returnNewDocument: true} // Optional, depending on if you want the updated doc.

    // Callback
    function callback(err, doc, raw) { 
        // Evaluate callback code...
        res.json({user:req.user})
    }
);
```

For more information on what each argument is for, see the [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) documentation.

Comment: No i need to update this in database.So that I can manage user keywords which I can use later for other information

Comment: So you want to push the tags sent in the request into the tags array of that user in the database?

Comment: Yes..so that I can that tags later